# Show that the NP vs coNP question relativises both ways

Tags: complexity-theory

The part that I have problems with is showing the existence of an oracle for which:

- $NP^B \neq coNP^B$

The hint:

consider the language: $L_B = \{ 1^n : \forall x \in {0,1}^n, x \in B \} $

Having seen the proof for $P^B \neq NP^B$ my thought process goes along the line that I want to show the following:

- $ L_B \in coNP^B$ for every B
- $ L_B \notin NP^B$ for some B

I do not really know how to fool a $coNP$ ...

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  Please ask only about the part you don't know how to solve.  There is no need to show us the other half of your exercise that you already know how to solve.

Comment: We're not particularly looking for posts that consist of just the statement of an exercise-style task and a statement that you don't know how to solve it or a request for us to show you a solution.  What progress have you made?  Do you have any specific question about the meaning of the hint? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: Have you tried showing the two things the hint asks you to show?  Can you prove either of them?  What have your attempts been?  I suggest you focus this question by asking about only one of those two, rather than asking about both.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the feedback, I've modified the question accordingly. I do not know how to construct B from ground up and at the same time fool the coNP TM on Lb